# MySQL: Why I get no results for a specific query on fulltext index?

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I have some trouble with a MySQL table and a fulltext index. My table structure looks similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE example_index (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    title tinytext,
    content text,
    FULLTEXT INDEX title (title),
    FULLTEXT INDEX titlecontent (title,content),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

As you can see I have created a fulltext index for the fields title and title and content in combination. Furthermore I have stored some data into this table like this:

```
id | title      | content
1  | Teamwork   | Example data
2  | CSV-Export | Testdata
```

If I try to get some data from this table via a match against query then I got one result for the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM example_index
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST('csv' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

**BUT** no results for this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM example_index
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST('Team' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Can someone tell me, why I got no results here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL fulltext indexes index **words**. This is a very important limitation. You do not have the word `team` in your data, but you do have the word `csv` because `-` is considered a word delimiter.

If you are looking for words **starting with** `team` then you can still use the fulltext index using the `*` operator within the string to be searched:

```
SELECT *
FROM example_index
WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST('Team*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If you would like to get records that contain the substring `team` **anywhere** within the indexed field, then MySQL fulltext index and fulltext search cannot help you. In this case you either need to revert to the good old `title like '%team%'` or you need to use a different fulltext search provider that can use MySQL.

Comment: Yeah ok thank you. I also tried this solution for some minutes ago and this works fine for me. Can you tell me if this is still more performant then a like query?

Comment: It depends. If the word `team` is always at the beginning of the field, then you can use `title like 'team%'`, which can utilise a traditional index on a field. In this case `like` may even be faster than a fulltext search. If the word starting with `team` can be anywhere within the field, so you need to use `title like '%team%'`, then `like` cannot use an index, so will be slower than a fulltext search.

Comment: Ok thank you :). Something like this would be great: '\*team\*', but this not working :(. So I have to use like in this case or I have to fill the content field for this fields like title: teamwork and content: team, work. So I could still use a match against query.

Comment: "Something like this would be great: '*team*', but this not working :(.  " - yeah, I told you that in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Full text search looks for *words* in the text not partial words.  Because your text contains "Teamwork", it does not contain team.  This is a limitation of many full text implementations.

If your data is not too big, you can use `like`:

```
SELECT *
FROM example_index
WHERE title LIKE '%Team%';
```

If you are just looking for titles that start with "Team", you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM example_index
WHERE title LIKE 'Team%';
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will take advantage of a regular index on `example_index(title)`.

I notice that MySQL now has an [n-gram parser](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search-ngram.html).  This parser is designed for non-English (primarily east Asian) languages.  However,  it might work on English as well.  You might be able to try this to do what you want.

Comment: Hm ok thx, but I think "like" is not the right thing for me, because my table will be contain a lot of rows in future. So like will be not performant enough to handle this. I have seen, that I could also use wildcards for fulltext index like this: AGAINST('Team*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and then I got a result, too. But I dont know if this is better then like, maybe you know something about this?

Comment: @Fox . . . Right, I forgot that MySQL supports that.  Of course, that should work better than `like`.  I think it will use the dictionary to expand the search terms to include all matching words in the dictionary.